# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: json, parsing

I am getting this error (as per Safari's Web inspector) but I cannot see why. Most reports of this error suggest that it is reading a HTML tag somewhere ... but I cannot see it.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
    oReq.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("myConsole").innerHTML = this.responseText;
myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
...
```

The third line of code dumps the responseText onto my webpage (into a DIV called 'myConsole'). This shows what I believe to be standard JSON code ... and contains no '<' characters.

The second line of code tries to parse the responseText and give the '<' token error.

The php data source looks like this:

```
$rowCount = 0;
    do { $rowCount += 1;
        $dbCurrentRow = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();
        $seats[$rowCount]['room'] = $dbCurrentRow['Room'];
        $seats[$rowCount]['seat'] = $dbCurrentRow['Seat'] * 1;
        $seats[$rowCount]['x'] =  $dbCurrentRow['x'] * 1;
        $seats[$rowCount]['y'] =  $dbCurrentRow['y'] * 1;
        $seats[$rowCount]['name'] =  "Joe Bloggs";
        $seats[$rowCount]['adno'] =  "01234";
        $seats[$rowCount]['ev6'] =  true;
        $seats[$rowCount]['eal'] =  true;
        $seats[$rowCount]['dpLast'] =  "LS";
        $seats[$rowCount]['dpCurrent'] =  "WA";
        $seats[$rowCount]['dpTarget'] =  "TG";
        $seats[$rowCount]['ma'] =  2 * 1;

        } while ($rowCount < $resultSet->num_rows);

echo json_encode($seats);
```

and the JSON output is this:

> {"1":{"room":"35","seat":1,"x":0,"y":0,"name":"Joe
>   Bloggs","adno":"01234","ev6":true,"eal":true,"dpLast":"LS","dpCurrent":"WA","dpTarget":"TG","ma":2},"2":{"room":"35","seat":2,"x":30,"y":60,"name":"Joe
>   Bloggs","adno":"01234","ev6":true,"eal":true,"dpLast":"LS","dpCurrent":"WA","dpTarget":"TG","ma":2},"3":{"room":"35","seat":3,"x":60,"y":0,"name":"Joe
>   Bloggs","adno":"01234","ev6":true,"eal":true,"dpLast":"LS","dpCurrent":"WA","dpTarget":"TG","ma":2},"4":{"room":"35","seat":4,"x":90,"y":90,"name":"Joe
>   Bloggs","adno":"01234","ev6":true,"eal":true,"dpLast":"LS","dpCurrent":"WA","dpTarget":"TG","ma":2}}

I do not believe it to be a server timing issue since it 'myConsole' dump precedes the error and works fine. It does not look like the JSON is faulty even with a 2d array. The strange thing is if I take the JSON output and save it as 'testDataSample.php' and link my main page directly to it then the same output works flawlessly.

```
   //oReq.open("get", "testDataSample.php", false); //Text JSON output works fine
    oReq.open("get", "getData.php", false); // Live from Server ... '<' error
    oReq.send();
```

Any suggestions as to what is wrong, or how I would track this down would be most welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Folbo, can you try console.log(this.responseText) ?

Comment: focus on `this.responseText`s value. I have a feeling you'll find whats wrong by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you raghav710 :-)

The console log showed it ... I had some comments at the top of the dataSource.php file which were being included in the echo.

Writing this to my web page ... they were ignored and invisible ... which means I could not see them, and could not see the difference between the two outputs; parsing the comments JSON caused the choke.

I have removed all of the comments at the top of my datasource.php and it work instantly.

Thank you again.